# how do I count the number of equal values in a dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare

What I am trying to do, is compare a test data set, built into a dictionary, to the learning data set, which is also built into a dictionary.  I have tried a number of ways, and I either get 0's back on all the checks, or I get answers that are impossible (I think that it's counting for all  int the testing set) rather than what it looks like it should be doing, which (SO I keep thinking) resetting the counts after each key/value pair in the training set.

Here's an example of code that's doing that.  help?

```
 public static void theTestingAlgorithm()
    {
        foreach (var testrecipe in Testing.sortedTestingData)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> runningNumbers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach(var learningRecipe in MakeData.SortedData)
            {
                runningNumbers.Add(learningRecipe.Key, 0);
            }                
            foreach(var testIngredient in testrecipe.Value)
            {
                foreach(var learningRecipe in MakeData.SortedData)
                {
                    if (learningRecipe.Value.Contains<string>(testIngredient))
                    {
                        runningNumbers[learningRecipe.Key]++;
                    }
                }
            }       
            string answer = evaluatetest(runningNumbers);
            runningNumbers.Clear();
            Answers.Add(testrecipe.Key, answer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by comparing two sets? You want the values that are not in both sets, or the values that are in set A but not set B, or vice-versa? Can you explain (with examples) of the input data for both sets and the expected output?

Comment: What I am trying to do, is have it count how many items in a testrecipe also exist in a learning recipe.  then noting that, and moving on to the next learning recipe.  evaluating each testrecipe against each learningRecipe.
For example:
test recipe has(in a List) "cheese" "potatoes" "eggs"
learning recipe one has "egg" "apple" "white flour"
learning recipe two has "vanilla" "banana" "rice" "milk"
the expected output would be dictionary <one, 1>,<two, 0>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to figure out how many times an ingredient appears in all of your test recipes.  I don't think you want to create your `runningNumbers` inside the foreach.

Here is a linq expression that may get you closer to what you are looking for...

```
        Dictionary<string, string[]> SortedTestingData = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        SortedTestingData.Add("1", new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });
        SortedTestingData.Add("2", new string[] { "d", "b", "e" });
        SortedTestingData.Add("3", new string[] { "d", "b", "f" });
        SortedTestingData.Add("4", new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });

        var runningNumbers = from vals in SortedTestingData
                             from val in vals.Value
                             group val by val into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 Value = g.Key,
                                 Count = g.Count()
                             };
```

This is a list of the count of each occurrence of each string in the values.

Comment: posted before I saw your comment in the question, will fix answer

Comment: It turns out that what I built above worked perfectly, the problem was in my sorting setup.  I fixed that, and now it works exactly as I thought that it should have!  thanks for the help though!

Having said that, I would like to use a linq setup, as it looks nicer.  If anyone knows how to do that, i would appreciate having it shared here.   Thanks!